# List index out of range; using def

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I can't figure out why I keep running into an error.
I have pointed out where I  would run into an error.

```
def lis_add(lis, element):
    lis = [ ]
    lis.append(element)
    return lis

def s_lis(lis):
    square = [ ]
    for i in range(len(lis)):
    square.append(lis[i] * lis[i])
    return square

def main():
    lis = [ ]
    for i in range(10):
        x = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
        lis = lis_add(lis, x)

    s = [ ]
    s = s_lis(lis)

    print("******* the input list *********")
    for i in range(10):
        print(lis[i]) *#error*
        *#list index out of range*

    print("******** the sqaure list *********")
    for i in range(len[s]):
        print(s[i])
    
    main() *#for some odd reason, I would also get an error here too*
```

Comment: your `list_add` function just creates a new list, adds an element, and returns it. You never continually add to the same list. Having that function doesn't make any sense anyway, `list` objects already have an `.append` method

Comment: Your `lis_add` is very odd. Really, in your main, you should have `lis.append(x)`. You're creating a new list, putting an element in in, then throwing it away and creating a new, single element list the next iteration.

Comment: Also, don't use `eval`. Use `int(input("Enter a number: "))` instead.

Comment: Side note - Including `*` around your comments is invalid syntactically.  Welcome to python!

Comment: Dedent the call to `main()` it's currently being called inside of `main()`

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

See this code right here:

```py
def lis_add(lis, element):
    lis = [ ]
    lis.append(element)
    return lis
```

More specifically right here:

```py
    lis = [ ]
```

It resets the list to have no elements each time it's called. So, your list only has a size of 1 when this is called:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(lis[i]) *#error*
```

And the main has an error because there is an error inside of main.

**Other suggestions:**

1. Use `int(input())`, not `eval`.
2. You write, `for i in range(len[s]):`, but it should be `for i in range(len(s)):`
3. Use `print(lis[:10])` instead of `for i in range(10): print(lis[i])` and `print(s)` instead of `for i in range(len(s)): print(s[i])`
4. Don't use `list[i]*list[i]`, instead use `list[i]**2`. Also, put a tab before the `square.append(lis[i] * lis[i])`
5. Use list comprehension, ie `square = [x**2 for x in lis]` and `lis = [input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(10)]`
6. Delete this code, it is unnecessary: `s = [ ]`

Also, the `main` in the last line has a tab, it's being called inside `main`. So, `main` is calling `main`. This doesn't return an error, it's called recursion, and can be really useful sometimes. Here, though, it's not. So I would recommend removing that tab.